# Jquery autosuggestion continue search with Case

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery search suggestions. The function is running ok. But now I want the function detect continue search.

Example : I want to search name David, I input in textbox just text : Da . And name suggestion will be show. Now if I click every where, div box suggestion will be close right ?.
and here what I want, when I back again click to textbox search, it will show div box suggestion last I input like the case : Da

Here is JS code so far :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".searchs").keyup(function() {
        var searchbox = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'searchword=' + searchbox;
        if (searchbox == '') {
            $("#display").hide();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "searchs.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#display").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
    $(".searchs").blur(function() {
        $("#display").hide();
    });
});
```

Any idea ?

Comment: check http://www.vulgarisoverip.com/2007/08/06/jquerysuggest-11/ or http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm

Comment: `$(".searchs").focus(function() {$("#display").show();});` would work? Are you using jquery autocomplete?

Comment: @Luccas I tried and ok now. But when searchbox empty and I click it show the empty box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to display the suggestion div when the user clicks in the text box, if there is text in the text box.

```
$(".searchs").focus(function()
{
  var seachbox = $(this).val(); /*note, you will need to change $(this) to the proper selector of your textbox*/
  if(seachbox != '')
  {
    $("#display").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome... That's worked. Thank you very much Logan Besecker.